# Dúvida sobre a behavior physics no Construct 2

Tags: construct-2

No exemplo do Construct 2 abaixo, como eu modifico para fazer o player andar também na vertical (essa configuração padrão só faz ele andar na horizontal)? O player tem essa forma mesmo de bola, e acho que esses ângulos servem para fazer o efeito de rolling, já que não tem animação no sprite.

Arquivo .capx: https://www.dropbox.com/s/reffzgb49i7hje7/Physics%20-%20rolling%20platformer.capx?dl=0[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa noite,

Seria bem mais fácil trabalhar modificando apenas os eixos X e Y, dessa forma:

Abaixo, o número 5 indicaria a velocidade do objeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desabilite os outros "is down" para não ter conflito.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito obrigado!